# No such file or directory from sh script

Tags: scripting, debian, sh

Looking for the origin of this error message:

```
Processing: +([^_]).flv
date: +([^_]).flv: No such file or directory
```

I started getting this at some point in the last few months (can't say when as I wasn't logging my cron output. I know, I know!).

When I originally wrote this, it worked ok for at least two months. I'm wondering if there was an sh update that broke it?

The script runs via crontab and gets all .flv files in the current directory without an underscore and processes each one. It then checks the modified date for files that have been created in the last 24 hours and runs the yamdi meta tag injector for .flv files.

It seems like it's not recognizing the pattern as a pattern and looking for it as an actual file to me. If I run this script from an ssh shell it works ok, it's only when running via cron that it gives this error.

```
shopt -s extglob
now=$(date +"%s")
for f in +([^_]).flv; do
   echo "Processing: $f"
        age=$(date -r  "$f" +"%s")
        calc=$(((now-age) / 60 / 60))
        if(( calc < 24 )); then
                echo "$f age=$calc"
                yamdi -i "$f" -o "$f".seek
                rm "$f"
                cp "$f".seek "$f"
                touch -d @$age "$f"

        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem of the wrong shell being used; make sure your script's first line represents the right shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

for bash, or whatever shell you wrote this for. You might want to check your environment variables that cron may set (that's a very common problem -- one assumes everything is set up correctly, but the environment that cron offers to scripts it executes is different).

Comment: I have that as the first line. Will investigate the cron environment.

Comment: This is what I find from reading your answer. Testing on the next cron run: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a line to crontab to switch to bash didn't seem to fix it.